# Python basic error handling

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to run the following code.

```
try:
    num1 = 7
    num2 = "Bob"
    print (num1 / num2)
except:
    print("oops")
    raise
```

Getting an exception, but without it first printing "oops" followed by the exceptions.

I'm new to this - what am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace for the exception you get?

Comment: Be real nice to see a full print out. My ESP is not what it once was

Comment: Isn't it obvious what the erorr is? Trying to do math on an int and a string??

Comment: Also, maybe 7 bobsths is a valid magic fraction in Python

Comment: @serk, are you saying that you know why oops isn't being printed?

Comment: I see 'oops' printed. You will need to show evidence that it does not print, state your exact version and any other code that might be in the script you are running.

Comment: I'm running this on SoloLearn for Android. 

That is the whole code, and giving me the expected error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'

I'm expecting "oops" followed by the above and trying to understand why my except: call isn't capturing it.

Comment: @J1raya. Looks like your output is capturing stderr only, not stdout

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the fact you have raise at the end. That raises an exception after you already caught one. remove that and it will work as you want it to.

fixed code:

```
try:
    num1 = 7
    num2 = "Bob"
    print(num1/num2)
except:
    print("oops")
    #raise
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why OP didn't see "oops" printed.

Comment: I missed that, however i do see it printed so i have no reasonable explanation for that.

Comment: The probable explanation is that the OP didn't post the real/full code and the question should be closed.

Comment: Thanks Foobar. My understanding is that if I use except: the error would be captured in that part of my code instead of earlier in the code much like you would with try catch in other languages.

Is that assumption on my part incorrect?

Comment: Pretty much, except: will go through if there is an error in the try: scope

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to include the actual error:

```
try:
    num1 = 7
    num2 = "Bob"
    print (num1 / num2)
except Exception as e:
    print ("oops")
    print e.message
```

Output:

```
oops
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
```